# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-promotion

When we reach public beta of course.

Most gaming forums have strict rules for posting links to other sites, so it won't be possible to make the site known there, which would be ideal to bring critical mass to the site.

What other options are there (besides twitter and all that)?

To the SE Team: Will there be cross promotion (a banner from another SE site for example)?

Comment: It would help if some of the larger game sites would find us an interesting resource of knowledge

Comment: see also: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370/gamingse-media-blitz-for-public-beta-launch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/gamingse-media-blitz-for-public-beta-launch)

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the forum link problem. Most forums do not have a problem with "spamming" links in your signature. So just put something like

```
[url=http://gaming.stackexchange.com]Q&A site for passionate gamers from all platforms (computers and consoles)[/url]
```

Answer (score 2):

I presume people have blogs (with readers, of course) and such which could be used to promote the site.  That's not a complete option, but it should work.  I get the feeling that with an active community and a bit of 'social media' influence we could get it moving.  Also, submission to slashdot etc would help.

Also, everyone should submit us to stumble, digg, and all those bookmarking sites.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be posting it on as many forums as I'm on. Apart from that, blogs, word of mouth and all other social doohickies.

Answer (score 0):

There is already cross-promotion from SO, highlighting questions in adboxes. I'm not sure if it goes for any of the other sites in the trilogy though, or whether he plans to have it done on other SE sites.