# GamingSE media blitz for public beta launch

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-promotion

I was thinking that we should try to get this site covered by the gaming media when the public beta goes live. I'm collecting links to the "send us tips" pages for several gaming sites. I'm making this post a community wiki, so please update the list as you see fit.

- Joystiq: http://www.joystiq.com/contact/tips/
- Eurogamer: http://www.eurogamer.net/contact.php
- IGN: http://games.ign.com/email.html
- GameSpy: http://www.gamespy.com/contact-us.html
- GameInformer: http://gameinformer.com/p/contactus.aspx (click on "Submit a News Tip" at the top)
- Kotaku: tips@kotaku.com
- 1up: feedback@1UP.com
- next-gen.biz (Edge magazine): contact@next-gen.biz
- GameDaily: <del>talk2games@aol.com</del> (I got a mailer-daemon error sending to this address) try those on this page: http://www.gamedaily.com/about/contact-us/
- Penny Arcade: tycho@penny-arcade.com (also gabe@penny-arcade.com, but Tycho writes the news posts so he's more likely to mention us)
- Gametrailers.com: bd@gametrailers.com (bd stands for business development)
- Gamespot: news@gamespot.com
- Ars Technica: Christina_Valencia@condenast.com
- G4tv: ???
- Gamesradar: ???
- GamePro: ???
- GiantBomb: ???

Remember, the public beta will open on Wednesday, July 14 at:

- US Pacific - 12 PM
- US Eastern - 3 PM
- UTC - 7 PM
- BST (London) - 8 PM
- CEST (Paris) - 9 PM
- Sydney - 5 AM Thursday

Comment: I'd recommend that if anyone within the beta "knows" someone from any sites, use that channel instead. Using those contact pages is like shooting into the sky, something might hit, but most likely not.

Comment: Great idea! ` `

Comment: xkcd and boingboing!

Comment: see also: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/326/how-do-we-promote-our-site

Comment: Out of curiosity, now that the public beta has been open for a few days, has there been any coverage of this site so far?

Answer (score 4):

This is great! Robert will work with you to coordinate -- he's on vacation at the moment but should be around early-ish next week to assist.

Comment: what kind of assistance/coordination were you thinking of? i was just thinking a lot of us could send in tips/emails to these sites when the site goes public tomorrow.

Comment: @kip just whatever we can do to help, mostly

Answer (score 2):

This is a great idea and *exactly* the type of activity we need to get this site going!

As @Jeff said, I'm here to help wherever I can. I don't know what I can do specifically with this list, but that's where you guys come in. I need ideas about we *can*  do to help. You are much more engaged in the gaming world than us so these idea *have* to come from you.

On a related note, I am in the process of [appointing a few members as provisional Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site/58056#58056). Part of their role will be to provide leadership from *within* the community — dedicated focus and leadership. They can help us make sure that great ideas don't go un-pursued.

It's easy to *write* about good ideas. But actually *acting* on those ideas will bring this system to an entirely new level!

Comment: thanks for the help. i contacted all of these sites when the beta went public, but i haven't really seen it covered anywhere. i think we'll have better luck with a grassroots-type approach--just people mentioning this site on gaming blogs/forums. and, like SO, the site will only *really* take off when it starts showing up above gamefaqs in google results when people search for video game help

Answer (score 1):

For the slashdotters among us:

http://slashdot.org/submission/1290978/stackoverflow-like-gaming-QampA-site-launched

Answer (score 0):

NeoGAF would also seem like a good place.

Comment: It's CW, so feel free to add it in yourself :-)