# Sponsorship opportunities for site?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-promotion

So the SEO team has come out with [some specifics](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/) for how they could [help promote](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326/how-do-we-promote-our-site).  I think the sponsorship opportunity makes the most sense for gaming.

What are the lan parties, tournaments, and gaming events that SEO could sponsor for Gaming.Stackexchange.com?

Comment: I'd love it if Jeff implemented [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/638/can-steam-be-added-as-an-openid-provider) to get at the very least a blog post from some Steam developer

Answer (score 10):

I know we have a fairly strong Starcraft 2 contingent on this site.  I'd be willing to take the time to organize a online Tournament and I'm even willing to put up $50 of my own money as first place prize.

Comment: +1, great idea.

Comment: Can we [HD](http://www.starcraftarena.net/index.php/contact) to cast it?

Comment: @Cross I assume you mean "Can we get HD to cast it?"  I don't know.  I don't know HD personally, though it maybe worth it.  We could try a number of other Casters out there, certainly some of them might have the free time to do this.  Alternatively I'd be willing to do audio commentary for the VoD, as I won't be playing in the tournament if I'm organizing it.

Comment: @tzenes Anyone would be good.  I mentioned HD because he has one of the larger followings, and you've already said you hate Husky.

Comment: Do you mean a tournament between high-end SC2 players, or between players who are already members of gaming.SE?

Comment: @Oak I had assumed community members as that would promote the community of the site, but it was suggested that we might try to make it larger to attract more attention

Comment: Well, if we want high visibility maybe all we need to do is to get the SE staff to sponsor an existing top-tier tournament. The pool prize for the HDH was like total 3500$, and look what it did to iRip, the sponsor: http://www.google.com/trends?q=irip&ctab=0&geo=all&date=2010&sort=0 - a serious spike in google searches during the tournament. And keep in mind that since SC2 players are gamers, our site is far more likely to interest them than iRip's.

Comment: Well I might be willing to Paypall a few buck to increase the price money for these things, so perhaps if others pitch in, we can raise a nice sum :-)

Comment: I've contacted Robert about this, we'll see if anything can be done about this great idea.