# What pro players would you like to see the most in a SC2 tournament?

Tags: discussion, community-tournament

In continuation to [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/978/gaming-se-starcraft-2-tournament-plan), we might be running a tournament in which some players are invited to participate without winning any sort of qualifiers. This is common in SC2 tournaments, as professional players are famous and give the tournament a lot of publicity.

What professional players would you like to see most in our tournament, and for what reason? Keep in mind our highest priority is getting the most visibility and publicity.

A list of professional players will hopefully appear [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7282/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-professional-starcraft-2-players) soon; many of their games can be watched on YouTube.

Comment: I see what you did there...

Comment: @alexanderpas I was hoping I'd get some answers to my question there until now :(

Answer (score 7):

Sadly the players I'd really like to see probably won't make it (ie. they live in Korea):

### Artosis

- He's hilarious
- Will do things like: double gas steal as Zerg
- Might go mass Spine Crawlers for epic lolz

### Tester

- Probably the best SC2 player alive
- One of the few Protoss players to constantly innovate
- Very aggressive style makes for a lot of enterainment

### TLO

- Probably the most fun player to watch
- Makes up weird strategies on the spot
- Might be the only player to go mass Battle Cruisers (+1)

### Sen

- Another Korean player who is Hyper aggressive (as Zerg no less)
- Gives you a view in to a very different style of play (most Zerg play reactionary).
- Amazing micro

### Jinro

- One of my favorite TL players (next to TLO)
- Pioneered Mass Ghosts
- Very tight control
- how could you not love this face:

[image]

Comment: +1 for TLO.  Love those off-the-cuff strategies.

Comment: @sjohnston yeah he's amazing to watch, unfortunately he chicken pox right now.  I hope he pulls through.

Answer (score 0):

I remember one of my favorite players to watch from the HDH invitational was [NonY](http://www.teamliquid.net/tsld/players/31_NonY).

- He's a very strong Protoss player
- He used the cool phoenix build effectively
- He was diverse in his tactics from game to game, not always sticking with the same build